# How does mysql do reverse resolution of IP addresses?

Tags: mysql

We rebooted a machine running mysql, and we're having some odd issues. Most processes from other machines are able to connect to without issue. We can also connect locally if we connect through the loopback address explicitly.

This works:

```
mysql -hlocalhost -utest_user -psecret_password
```

When we run the command:

```
mysql -h192.168.1.10 -utest_user -psecret_password
```

locally on the machine we get the following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user `test_user`@`SERVER_123`
```

We had the following users:

```
test_user@localhost
test_user@%
```

We have fixed the issue by adding the following user:

```
test_user@SERVER_123
```

Where SERVER_123 is the unqualified name of the machine.
We don't know why we had to add that additional user, and we don't want to keep it, but we also don't know why adding it fixed the issue.

Why does connecting from the local machine, via IP (i.e. mysql -ha.b.c.d -utest_user -ppsswd) fail to match the `test_user@%` user, but will match `test_user@machine_name`, where machine_name is the unqualified name of the machine?

Here is the user table

```
anonymous    %
anonymous    SERVER_123
anonymous    localhost
test_user_2  %
test_user_3  %
root         ::1
root         127.0.0.1
root         SERVER_123
root         localhost
```

Note: Figured out the issue. Somehow rebooting the machine must have changed how 192.168.1.10 resolved so that it resolved to SERVER_123. That then caused logins from 192.168.1.10 to match `test_user`@`SERVER_123`.

Comment: (As is often the case), the error message is critical here to diagnosing exactly what's going on.  Please include it.

Comment: Check if you have an anonymous user (empty username) with your server as host (or rather, check all your anonymous users). It would take precedence over a non-anonymous user without a host.

Comment: @eggyal - Added the error messge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. There is an anonymous user which is matching before the specific user. I'm not sure what happened during the reboot that caused reverse resolution to change, but we had a user ''@'SERVER_123' which must have started matching. Removing the anonymous user fixed the issue, and we no longer need to have privileges for `test_user@SERVER_123`.

Answer (score 5):

I would take a look at the sorting rules in this section of the MySQL documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connection-access.html

> It is possible for the client host name and user name of an incoming connection to match more than one row in the user table.

It could be that your user is identified as another user with a different password. What other entries are present in your user table?

**Update based on new information:** Your login was identified as the ''@'%' user. This user either has different credentials, or is missing the necessary permissions.

Comment: It shouldn't have matched anything else. I'm still not sure why user@% didn't match, while user@local_machine_name did.

Comment: @bpeikes, can you share the user table entries?

Answer (score 3):

You can follow the MySQL documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/host-cache.html), which talks about the DNS lookup optimization and also the process how this is achieved. To point out one point from the documentation is the following:

> The MySQL server maintains a host cache in memory that contains information about clients: IP address, host name, and error information. The server uses this cache for nonlocal TCP connections. It does not use the cache for TCP connections established using a loopback interface address (127.0.0.1 or ::1), or for connections established using a Unix socket file, named pipe, or shared memory.

And there is another point that help you resolve this is with the introduction of the following parameter:

```
skip-name-resolve
```

You can follow the article here that suggests that MySQL authenticates based on IP addresses or Hostnames - Article link [here](http://www.vionblog.com/skip-name-resolve-to-speed-up-mysql-and-avoid-problems/).

> By default MySQL grants authentication on users based on IP address or hostnames. When there is a connection from a particular host, MySQL does a reverse DNS lookup and compares the hostname and IP address.

Hope this helps to answer your question!

Comment: What I don't understand is why user_name@% would not match when connecting from the local machine via IP (real ip, not loopback), but would work when connecting via IP.

Comment: Well that's a strange problem, but did my solution work for your situation @bpeikes?

Comment: This is a production system, so I can't try much in the way of changing server parameters that require a restart of the service.

Comment: @bpeikes, I get that!

Answer (score 3):

First of all remember only **127.0.0.1, ::1, localhost etc...** are considered as loopback addresses not **192.168.1.10 or SERVER_123** as you may be accepting.

Yes! **192.168.1.10** should match for wildcard host **%**, but unfortunately beside test_user_2 and test_user_3 I don't see **test_user** entry in provided user table data.

In addition on Linux you may use `/etc/hosts` file to map ip address to hostname