# MYSQLDUMP: Change thing after @ symbol

Tags: mysql

I have the correct parameters for mysqldump:

```
mysqldump -uUSERNAME -p -hREMOTE_HOST_URL REMOTE_DB_NAME > PATH_TO_DUMP_LOCATION.sql
```

When I execute the command, I always get `Got error 1045` stating that the hostname(?) after the @ symbol is incorrect. Ex:Correct_Username@Wrong_Hostname.

How do I change it?

"Exact" command and feedback:

```
: mysqldump -ujosh -p -hresearch.edu datab > C:\S.sql
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'josh'@'josh.vpn.es.edu' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
```

Comment: Changed. @Dake K

Comment: Your local station hostname is detected as `Wrong_Hostname` from MySQL server. Check where MySQL server's OS takes this name from (who is its DNS server, for example).

Comment: please show the exact entire error message

Comment: where is this '@' that you refer to?  -h takes only a host name (a domain name like 'foo.example.com') or an ip address

Comment: @ysth Updated post. The '@' is after the username. In the post's example, it would be the 'josh.vpn.es.edu' that I want to change.

Comment: You would change it by connecting from a different host.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/49177372/17389 has some discussion and links to how that is found and what effect it has

Answer (score 0):

First check **REMOTE_HOST_URL** with ping and make sure it's same server where MySQL server is installed or use IP of MySQL server.
then check `show grants for 'josh'@'josh.vpn.es.edu';` in MySQL server if you have provided access to user josh to connect from josh.vpn.es.edu.
also verify the password.